# How does this type of webservice throw slide images using JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

```
{
  "slider_images": 
    [
      {"image":"http://www.jcwholesale.co.uk/slider_img/big/1_1433518577.jpg"},
      {"image":"http://www.jcwholesale.co.uk/slider_img/big/1_1433519494.jpg"},
      {"image":"http://www.jcwholesale.co.uk/slider_img/big/1_1433515458.jpg"},
      {"image":"http://www.jcwholesale.co.uk/slider_img/big/1_1432292878.jpg"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: please rephrase your question? do you want your webpage to render these images? are you getting this array from an ajax call?

Comment: yes, i want to render this four images in this arrays , sliding  images in every some 3 or 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

using `jquery`:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({

       url: 'get_images',
       method: 'POST',
       data: {}

  }).done(function(data) {
       //data should be your response object like specified in the question.
       var container = $('#div_where_to_show images');

       $.each(data.slider_images, function(_, image_obj){
            container.append('<img>' + image_obj.image + '</img>');
       })

  }).fail(function(error) {

        alert('failed');
   });
```